# How to write query for count of a column in jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a table attendance in which columns are id,name,date,status.Here what's the my problem is,If i select two dates(start date and end date) in my html page,I want to generate a attendance report of a student between the range of dates with name also no of present days also.How to write query for selecting name of the student and count of present days of particular student.For all help thanks in advance.

i wrote query like below.

```
String sql = "select student_name,count(status) from attendance where attendance.date>=? and attendance.date<=? and attendance.status=?";


try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema", "root", "root");
        String sql = "select student_name from attendance where attendance.date>=? and attendance.date<=? and attendance.status=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        //pstmt.setString(1, "Present");
        pstmt.setString(1, stDate);
        pstmt.setString(2, enDate);
        pstmt.setString(3, "Present");

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
            int colCount =  rsmd.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("colCount :" + colCount);


            System.out.println("count>>"+colCount);
            StudentMark ge = new StudentMark();

            ge.setStudentName(rs.getString(1));

            stList.add(ge);

        }

        out.print(stList);
        out.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What is the Problem with your query?

Comment: I did not get right count of  status from my table.

Comment: Please add sample data

Comment: Do you want number of columns in the result set or number of rows in result set? ResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount() will always be 1 since student_name is the only column in the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ResultSetMetaData` to get the column count for any `select` query's result.

```
ResultSet rs= ... //Statement's result.
ResultSetMetaData rsmd= rs.getMetaData();

int colCount =  rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

Comment: From above code i get colCount num is 1 only,but i have two dates with status present.